# Type error in a simple code to get jsonwebtoken

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I learn something new, I usually write code, in which I can use it, but I try this code to be as simple as possible.
Now I am learning the basics of JsonWebToken, so I have made a very small database in MongoDB - just a couple of documents with 3 fields - _id, name, age and username. Then I wrote a few lines of code in node.js.
But the problem is that I always receive "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_id')". If I leave the payload empty( by removing 'userId') then I get a response
with the security token, but the data property in it is null - "data": {"doc": null}.
I use postman to get responses, I choose POST,then raw and JSON and then write in the body section just {"username: "john25"} or {"username": "george15"} or {"username": "jim35"} and send it to localhost:5000/login
Can you tell where the problem lies?

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    age: { type: Number, required: true },
    username: { type: String, required: true }, 
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

function login(req, res){
    const {username} = req.body;    
User.findOne({  username })
    .then(function(doc){ 
        const userId = doc._id;
        const token = jwt.sign({ userId }, 'abc123', {expiresIn: 250});
        return res.status(200).json({status: 'success', token, data: {doc}}); 
    });                     
}

app.post('/login', login);

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.epwfttj.mongodb.net/?       retryWrites=true&w=majority')
.then(() => app.listen(5000))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Does anyone have a clue how to get the actual data of the user in the response?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You have no error handling so that's why you can't detect the bug. First make sure you are sending valid JSON in postman and that the Content-type is correct in Postman headers.

Since you are still learning just focus on getting your code working using callback in your route handler then you can abstract that away into a function once you are confident it's working like so:

```js
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => { //< Mark callback as async
   console.log('body=', req.body); // Make sure body parser is working
   try{
      const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }); // Use await
      const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, 'abc123', {expiresIn: 250});
      return res.status(200).json({
         status: 'success', 
         token, 
         data: user 
      });
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err); // Error in console will tell you what's wrong
      return res.status(500).json({
         message: 'Error on server'
      });
   }
});
```

Add a get route to return all users:

```js
app.get('/users', async (req, res) => {
   try{
      const users = await User.find();
      return res.status(200).json({
         status: 'success', 
         users : users 
      });
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({
         message: 'Error on server'
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: I tried this too, but I still receive TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_id'). The only difference is that I now have it only in the command prompt, in the console of the postman now it says 'Error on server' as expected. Error handling or not, it is still not working. maybe there is something in the postman, I don't know. I am empty of ideas what more I can do to get the proper response

Comment: Your `app.use(bodyParser.json());` is going to parse the body of the request so you need to make sure you are sending valid JSON through the postman options. You can see if the body is being parsed by doing `console.log(req.body)` inside the `app.post` route handler. I will add it to the answer..

Comment: This is what I get now:body= { username: 'george15' }
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_id')
    at C:\Users\Miriyan\Desktop\oct23back\app.js:24:45
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Comment: @MiriyanAsenov that's good. Your postman JSON is being sent correctly and your bodyParser is working. This just means you don't have a User with a username = george15. You need to look in your database to see what you actually have. If you do `User.find()` it will return all users.

Comment: For some reason unknown to me, postman returns empty array :  {
    "status": "success",
    "users": []
}

Comment: Do you have any documents in your `users` collection? Can you post a screenshot of Compass with the User documents shown? Make sure you are connecting to a database that has your actual documents.